# Save a request in a session

Tags: php, symfony, session-variables

I have the following code inside a controller:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$session = $request->getSession();
```

I'm POSTing some data to that controller (from a form). I want to save the posted data in a session variable. Is that possible?

Maybe serializing the request object? If this is the correct way, how would I serialize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to how you can get all of your session values into an array using `$session->all()`, you can fetch all of the `request` values using `$request->request->all()`, so your final product would be:

```
$session->set('postData', $request->request->all());
```

To get the data back:

```
$postDataFromBefore = $session->get('postData');
```

And you access the values of `$postDataFromBefore` like you would access any traditional `$_POST` array since Symfony preserves the session data in the same data type. So `$_POST['my_value']` would translate right to `$postDataFromBefore['my_value']`.

Comment: Just to make sure, the `$postDataFromBefore` from your code would contain the same data and data type as `$this->getRequest()` from the first request, right?

Comment: @alexandernst The object that comes from `$this->getRequest()`, no. However all of the `POST` values that returned as an array from `$request->request->all()` would be preserved the same way. You could potentially store the Request object directly into the session but it depends if the object is serializable or not! (With Symfony, this is likely.)